# Multiple markers at this line - Line breakpoint:HelloListView [line: 34] - onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long) for the following code

Tags: android, android-adapterview

can any one help me how to  resolve this.
Multiple markers at this line   - Line breakpoint:HelloListView [line: 34] - onItemClick(AdapterView, View,       int, long) for the following code.

this is the error for the following code.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```